# Facebook likes disappears from my blog posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a blog where I publicate posts weekly, or whatever. The point is I added opengraph meta elements to my HTML code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="...">
<meta property="og:description" content="...">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://...">
```

When I changed my code then disappears the Facebook likes from my posts. Thats all of my modifications. I think this isn't a big thing.

Is there any reason why disappers the likes?

Comment: Likes and shares are bound to the URL – if you change the URL to a new one, you will “lose” the old ones. I assume that’s what has happened here, when you started to explicitly specify an `og:url` value. If Facebook previously used another URL to identify your post, then you need to find that URL first (revert your changes, and see what the FB debug tool finds as “final URL” for your content.) How to properly go about changing URLs if you want to keep likes and shares, is described within the social plugins FAQ.

Comment: I use same URL in `og:url` field what is the real and only one URL of the page.